# Use of hooks with conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a multi-step page for creating course. basically the UI looks like this

[image]

Each step is a separate component. The code for rendering looks like this:

```
const getStepContent = step => {
    if (isRequesting)
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Skeleton height={40} variant="text" />
                <Skeleton height={40} variant="text" />
                <Skeleton height={40} variant="text" />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return (
                <CourseBasicInfo
                    onInputChange={onInputChange}
                    onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
                    onAutoCompleteChange={onAutoCompleteChange}
                    values={{
                        name: values.name,
                        fieldEids: values.fieldEids,
                        categoryEids: values.categoryEids,
                        agesFrom: values.agesFrom,
                        agesTo: values.agesTo,
                        type: values.type
                    }}
                    errors={errors}
                    touched={touched}
                    t={t}
                    isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
                    categories={categories}
                    setFieldTouched={setFieldTouched}
                    setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                    handleChange={handleChange}
                />
            )
        case 1:
            return (
                <FormikEditor
                    name="description"
                    key="description"
                    errors={errors}
                    touched={touched}
                    onChange={onEditorChange}
                    value={values.description}
                />
            )
        case 2:
            return (
                <FormikEditor
                    name="prerequisites"
                    key="prerequisites"
                    errors={errors}
                    touched={touched}
                    onChange={onEditorChange}
                    value={values.prerequisites}
                />
            )
        case 3:
            return (
                <FormikEditor
                    name="topics"
                    key="topics"
                    errors={errors}
                    touched={touched}
                    onChange={onEditorChange}
                    value={values.topics}
                />
            )
        default:
            return 'Unknown step'
    }
}
```

I use hooks inside `CourseBasicInfo`, As soon as the user presses the next button index is incremented by 1 and so the next step should render. But instead, I get [error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=300) indicating a problem with hooks.
The surprising part is: This error is not being encountered on local, only after project build.

Is there any workaround for using hooks along with conditional rendering?

Comment: there is no hook in your code - conditionally rendering *Components* is perfectly OK, the error seems to be inside `CourseBasicInfo`, `FormikEditor` (or inside any of the props you pass to those components) - do you use `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` [eslint plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin)?

Comment: Using hooks is okay as long as it is before any of the conditions.
If you need the condition to apply to the hook. Just have the condition repeated inside the hook.

Comment: @Aprillion yes I use hooks inside both of the components. Nope I don't use eslint plugin. But since it's rendering conditionally, it uses 2 hooks for ``CourseBasicInfo`` and 1 for ``FormikEditor`` and I think that causes the error. Do you think that's the point?

Comment: I don't believe that would cause problems. The number of hooks must be constant only within 1 component, not within the whole application, that would be a crazy requirement. The eslint plugin would tell you what's the problem.

Comment: @Aprillion I agree with you, I found another interesting point: Inside render method of the component that hosts ``CourseBasicInfo`` and ``FormikEditor``, I call a method as follows: ``{renderContent(activeStepIndex)}`` extracting the function content to the render itself solved the problem really crazy!! and there is another crazy part about this bug: It only happens after I build the project, meaning that on HMR this problem doesn't occur at all.